# How do I pass SaveAsDialog's result to RelayCommand?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Here is the flow of my problem:

1. User clicks on "Save" button
2. The "Save As" dialog appears for choosing the destination path
3. Execute the RelayCommand of "Save" button 's click event

Currently I do not have any idea about:

1. How to open the dialog & execute the RelayCommand with EventToCommand binding
2. How to pass the selected path of "Save As" dialog into the RelayCommand

I am using MVVM Light library.

Answer (score 2):

While I think Dmitriy Reznik answer is fairly good, another solution would be to use the button's command to do most of the work in the ViewModel. This doesn't strictly follow the MVVM pattern, but it may be the easier to implement.

Set the Command on your Button to a ICommand on the ViewModel. The ICommand launches the SaveFileDialog and writes the file to disk once the dialog has closed. Since you're using MVVM Light I'll use a RelayCommand to implement ICommand.

Xaml:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SaveAsClickCmd}/>
```

Code:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand SaveAsClickCmd
    {
        get {
            return _saveAsClickCmd ?? (_saveAsClickCmd = new RelayCommand(() => {
                var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() != true)
                    return;
                using (var stream = dialog.OpenFile()) {
                    //write out file to disk
                }
            }));
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand _saveAsClickCmd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a class based on the DialogMessage class in the MVVM Light library (you will need to reference the MVVM Light libraries)

```
public class SaveFileDialogMessage : GenericMessage<string>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SaveFileDialogMessage" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="content">The content.</param>
    /// <param name="filter">The filter.</param>
    /// <param name="callback">The callback.</param>
    public SaveFileDialogMessage(string content, string filter, Action<bool?, string> callback)
        : base(content)
    {
        Filter = filter;
        Callback = callback;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SaveFileDialogMessage" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="content">The content.</param>
    /// <param name="filter">The filter.</param>
    /// <param name="callback">The callback.</param>
    public SaveFileDialogMessage(object sender, string content, string filter, Action<bool?, string> callback)
        : base(sender, content)
    {
        Filter = filter;
        Callback = callback;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SaveFileDialogMessage" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="target">The target.</param>
    /// <param name="content">The content.</param>
    /// <param name="filter">The filter.</param>
    /// <param name="callback">The callback.</param>
    public SaveFileDialogMessage(object sender, object target, string content, string filter, Action<bool?, string> callback)
        : base(sender, target, content)
    {
        Filter = filter;
        Callback = callback;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a callback method that should be executed to deliver the result
    /// of the message box to the object that sent the message.
    /// </summary>
    public Action<bool?, string> Callback { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the title.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The title.
    /// </value>
    public string Title { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets or gets the filter property.
    /// </summary>
    public string Filter { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Utility method, checks if the <see cref="Callback" /> property is
    /// null, and if it is not null, executes it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result">The result that must be passed
    /// to the dialog message caller.</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
    public void ProcessCallback(bool? result, string fileName)
    {
        if (Callback != null)
        {
            Callback(result, fileName);
        }
    }
```

Then in your ViewModel you have something like this:

```
    var dialog = new SaveFileDialogMessage("Title", "XML Files" + "|" + ".xml", ProcessSaveFileDialog);
    Messenger.Default.Send(dialog);

    private void ProcessSaveFileDialog(bool? dialogResult, string fileName)
    {
            ..........
    }
```

and in your View constructor:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new instance of the <see cref="MainView"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messenger.Default.Register<SaveFileDialogMessage>(this, msg =>
                                                                {
                                                                    var sfd = new SaveFileDialog { Filter = msg.Filter, Title = msg.Title };
                                                                    var result = sfd.ShowDialog();
                                                                    msg.ProcessCallback(result, sfd.FileName);
                                                                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I won't go chasing MVVM purity by making everything done in the viewModel and would cheat a bit saving some code for the code-behind. It's not that unusual that components aren't MVVM-ready out-of-the-box, and the "chase" can take time while customers lose value.

Anyway, for the current question there's this approach:

1. Create an event in viewModel called OnSelectSavePath which returns string (filePath)
2. On click viewModel raises an event
3. Page/UserControl/Window subscribes to an event with a method that runs OpenFileDialog or something
4. Page/UserControl/Window returns selected string from that method
5. ViewModel receives string from an event and uses it to its fullest.

This way you correctly detach viewModel from the presentation layer (not giving out the details of selection form) while still providing the functionality needed.

Another approach would be to define custom openFileDialog that would support MVVM. You would pass current viewModel to the dialog and the dialog would update the selectedPath property on the viewmodel.

Better yet, you could just do it in codeBehing and then call some method on the viewModel with the selectedPath property. That saves you all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but for beginners (like me) it's important to get the *right* examples.

Personally, I don't like any of the examples above as it is my feeling that declaring a dialog in the ViewModel violates the MVVM pattern. IMHO, the ViewModel must not know about any UI related controls such as dialogs or message boxes.

While googling, I found this: http://www.matt.digital/mvvm-light-communicating-across-layers-with-services/ which IMHO is a perfect example of how to present dialogs in a MVVM-like way.